# How to change font color of nested HTML elements at once

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create hover effect on ul, I am trying to figure out a way to change the font color of elements which are in ul on hover.

Right now I am using hover on single element like this:

```css
.wt-description p:hover {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <ul class="wt-categoryvtwo wt-categoryvthree">
    <li>
      <div class="wt-categorycontentvtwo">
        <figure><img src="#" alt="Category"></figure>
        <div class="wt-cattitlevtwo">
          <h4><a href="#">Mobiles</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="wt-description">
          <p>ios | android | ionic | pwa | flutter | react native more...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but I have to hover on that specific element to trigger the hover effect.

I just want to know is there a way to change font color of a and p tag to white at once on hover?

Your response on this is really appreciated.

Comment: First, your HTML is invalid, it is missing the closing `ul` and `li` tags. If you want to change multiple elements at once, search for the nearest common parent and apply the CSS there or combine multiple classes for one css rule

Comment: do you only want to use pure css? or you can use javascript  or javascript libraries(jquery)?

Comment: "I am trying to create hover effect on ul"... so apply the hover effect to the `ul`, not the `p`?

Answer (score 1):

Add the hover to the element that contains both of the elements. In this case you can do it on the li or the first child in the li. Or if it is supposed to be the whole UL at once as your description says, put the hover on the UL.

```css
li:hover, li:hover a {
  color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <ul class="wt-categoryvtwo wt-categoryvthree">
    <li>
      <div class="wt-categorycontentvtwo">
        <figure><img src="#" alt="Category"></figure>
        <div class="wt-cattitlevtwo">
          <h4><a href="#">Mobiles</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="wt-description">
          <p>ios | android | ionic | pwa | flutter | react native more...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Keep both a and p elements inside a div and apply the hover effect on that, in this case both will change to white at same time as you requested.

```
<div class="col-12">
<ul class="wt-categoryvtwo wt-categoryvthree">
<li>
   <div class="wt-categorycontentvtwo">
      <figure><img src="#" alt="Category"></figure>
      <div class="selector">
         <div class="wt-cattitlevtwo">
            <h4><a href="#">Mobiles</a></h4>
         </div>
         <div class="wt-description">
            <p>ios | android | ionic | pwa | flutter | react native more...</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

make links to inherit color and then apply hover effect on div to simultaneously make both elements text white:

```
a{
  color:inherit;
}
.selector:hover{
 color:white;
}
```

Hope  this helps :)